# How to make a file from destination don't be deleted when using the "--delete" flag in rsync?

Tags: rsync

## The context

Let's suppose we have the following directory organization

```sh
mkdir -p a/foo a/bar b
touch a/1.txt a/2.txt a/foo/b.txt a/bar/b.txt
touch b/b.txt
```

```sh
tree --noreport
```

```
.
├── a
│   ├── 1.txt
│   ├── 2.txt
│   ├── bar
│   │   └── b.txt
│   └── foo
│       └── b.txt
└── b
    └── b.txt
```

and we want to transfer all the files in directory `a` (source) to directory `b` (destination) by using the `--delete` flag but don't want the `b/b.txt` file to be deleted.

One might think that the following command accomplish this. However, note that the file `b/b.txt` is deleted.

```sh
rsync -r --delete a/ b
```

```
.
├── a
│   ├── 1.txt
│   ├── 2.txt
│   ├── bar
│   │   └── b.txt
│   └── foo
│       └── b.txt
└── b
    ├── 1.txt
    ├── 2.txt
    ├── bar
    │   └── b.txt
    └── foo
        └── b.txt
```

The reason why the `--delete` flag has been used is because I want to have an exact copy of the source directory `a` in the destination directory `b` but let's call it not "exact" because I want the file `./b/b.txt` not to be deleted by the `--delete` flag.

## What I've tried

### Using the `--exclude` flag

Apparently, we can get this effect by using the `--exclude` flag.

```sh
rsync -r --delete --exclude=b.txt a/ b
```

```
.
├── a
│   ├── 1.txt
│   ├── 2.txt
│   ├── bar
│   │   └── b.txt
│   └── foo
│       └── b.txt
└── b
    ├── 1.txt
    ├── 2.txt
    ├── bar
    ├── b.txt
    └── foo
```

The problem with doing this is that even though the file `./b/b.txt` is not deleted, the files `a/foo/b.txt` and `a/bar/b.txt` are not copied to `b`.

### Using the `--exclude` flag using a full path

```sh
rsync -r --delete --exclude=./b/b.txt a/ b
```

```
.
├── a
│   ├── 1.txt
│   ├── 2.txt
│   ├── bar
│   │   └── b.txt
│   └── foo
│       └── b.txt
└── b
    ├── 1.txt
    ├── 2.txt
    ├── bar
    │   └── b.txt
    └── foo
        └── b.txt
```

As we can see above, executing this deletes the file `./b/b.txt`.

### Using the `--filter` flag

Apparently, the following gets the desired result.

```sh
rsync -r --delete --filter='P b.txt' a/ b
```

```
.
├── a
│   ├── 1.txt
│   ├── 2.txt
│   ├── bar
│   │   └── b.txt
│   └── foo
│       └── b.txt
└── b
    ├── 1.txt
    ├── 2.txt
    ├── bar
    │   └── b.txt
    ├── b.txt
    └── foo
        └── b.txt
```

However, if we were to delete `a/foo/b.txt`.

```sh
rm -f a/foo/b.txt
```

```
.
├── a
│   ├── 1.txt
│   ├── 2.txt
│   ├── bar
│   │   └── b.txt
│   └── foo
└── b
    ├── 1.txt
    ├── 2.txt
    ├── bar
    │   └── b.txt
    ├── b.txt
    └── foo
        └── b.txt
```

The file wouldn't be deleted from the destination directory if we execute `rsync` again.

```sh
rsync -r --delete --filter='P b.txt' a/ b
```

```
.
├── a
│   ├── 1.txt
│   ├── 2.txt
│   ├── bar
│   │   └── b.txt
│   └── foo
└── b
    ├── 1.txt
    ├── 2.txt
    ├── bar
    │   └── b.txt
    ├── b.txt
    └── foo
        └── b.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you avoid the `--delete` flag, files on the destination won't be deleted.

```
rsync -rt a/ b
```

Seeing an update to your question that explains why you need to use delete, the following command will avoid updating or deleting the topmost `b.txt`

```
rsync -rt --delete --exclude '/b.txt' a/ b/
```

The leading `/` on the exclude filename binds it to the start of the source/destination pathname, which prevents it matching `bar/b.txt`, etc. (Think of it as equivalent to `^` if you're familiar with REs.)

---

Not strictly on-topic, but if you use `-rt` rather than `-r` then file times will also be copied. This means that when you repeat the `rsync` it can skip files that have not been changed since they were last copied. If you're copying to a native filesystem (i.e. not NTFS or vFAT) then use `-a` (or even `-aHXA`) instead of `-rt` and copy more of the metadata.

Comment: I've edited my question so that it is explained why using the `--delete` flag is necessary in the context of the question.

Comment: In the context of your example is it just `b/b.txt` that is not to be deleted?

Comment: That's right. Note that that file doesn't exist in `a`.

Comment: That's fine; my updated solution avoids touching the topmost `b.txt` in any way

Comment: Thanks, it worked like a charm! I tested it by not using the leading slash at the end of the destination directory and it still worked (i.e. wrote `b` instead of `b/`. Just letting you in case you think the trailing slash is necessary.

Comment: You're right; the trailing slash isn't necessary or relevant for the destination, but it is relevant for the source. I tend to use it on both sides for consistency

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-b` (backup) option to `rsync`. The file `b/b.txt` will be renamed to `b/b.txt~`, you can rename it back to the previous name when `rsync` command is finished.

You can also use the `--suffix` parameter to specify another suffix (instead of `~`) to be added to the filename, or `--backup-dir` parameter to move the file to another directory instead of renaming it. See `man rsync` for details.